# Unity 3d Score increase incrementally when hit by "bullet"

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, count

I have some code that is supposed to count, one at a time, an enemy being been hit by a ""bullet" and then that enemy is destroyed on collision. My problem is that when I hit the enemy, the score goes up by one and whenever I hit another enemy, it wont increase to two (it stays at one).

I have my canvas and text components working and the script is attached to the enemy.

```
int score=0;
int displayScore=0;
public Text scoreUI;

private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
{
    GameObject other = collision.gameObject;
    switch (other.tag)
    {
        case "player":
            break;
        case "bullet":
            displayScore++; //Increment the display score by 1

            scoreUI.text = displayScore.ToString(); 
            //Write it to the UI

            Destroy(this.gameObject);
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: display score should be a static int

Comment: If your script is attached to each enemy and your score variable is not static, each enemy will have his own instance of score... That is your mistake ;) you already have solutions below but it's good to understand what was wrong

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a score manager having a static score value in it. And attach this script to another gameobject (which you won't destroy):

```
public class ScoreManager: MonoBehaviour { 

   public static int score;
   private int displayScore;
   public Text scoreUI;

   void Start(){
      score = 0;
      displayScore = 0;
   }

   void Update(){
      if(score != displayScore){
         displayScore = score;
         scoreUI.text = displayScore.ToString(); 
      }
   }
}
```

And when you want to increase your score just call it by:

```
ScoreManager.score++;
```

Comment: omg thank you, who knew having a code count would be so difficult